# Elastic search `filter` query not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, elasticsearch

I have been trying to find out entries which match query 'abc' and from all those entries returned by multi_match i need to filter entries based on entries which contain given business_id where business_id is one of the fields.

i have tried with below query but no records returned from search even though there is one record satisfying both must and filter query.
Problem is in filter query as when i commented it got 2 records returned by multi_match as required and now i want to filter these records based on business_id so finally should get only one record but filter query is not working.

```
GET customer/_search
{
              "query": {
                  "bool": {
                      "must": {
                          "dis_max": {
                              "queries":
                                  {
                                      "multi_match": {
                                          "query": "abc",
                                          "type": "phrase_prefix",
                                          "fields": ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "city", "state", "zip", "country"]
                                      }
                                  }
                          }
                      },
                      "filter": {
                          "term": {
                              "business_id": business_id
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
```

[Here is how my records in index looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeVO2.png)

Comment: I believe this should be working as you'd like it too. Have you tried uncommenting the must or the filter part to see which part of the query is your problem? Also, how does your index look like? `phrase_prefix` will not work on keywords for example.

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into it. Problem is in filter query as when i commented it got 2 records returned by multi_match as required and now i want to filter these records based on business_id so finally should get only one record but filter query is not working. Also, have tried removing `phrase_prefix` but didn't got required result

Comment: It's hard to provide much more without knowing what your index looks like. Can you provide the relevant part of your mapping, and maybe the document that you would like to match?

Comment: Hey i have added image of my index structure in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GET customer/_search
{
              "query": {
                  "bool": {
                      "must": {
                          "dis_max": {
                              "queries":
                                  {
                                      "multi_match": {
                                          "query": "abc",
                                          "type": "phrase_prefix",
                                          "fields": ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "city", "state", "zip", "country"]
                                      }
                                  }
                          }
                      },
                      "filter": {
                          "match": {
                              "business_id": business_id
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
```

Solution to my Question . Now filter query is working fine as i have replaced `term` with `match`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug this, I suggest that you'll only search with the `must` section in the query and see that you get the result you expect, and then do the same with only the `filter` part.

What you want to see is that on both queries you'll get the document you expect. I believe that one of them should not return the document you expect, and then you could try to understand why (and update the question if needed).

If both `must` and `filter` return the doc you expect then the above query should work just fine. Also, if that doesn't work, please add the document that you expect to receive back

Comment: Hey Ziv, i had Modified the question.Please do check and let me know if you have a solution

Comment: I suggest you start by removing the `dis_max` query and put the `multi_match` directly under the `must` section.

Comment: But the `must` part is working fine. Error is in `filter` part which i couldn't find.So, why to remove `dis_max` and `multi_match` when they are working as required.